# Which string gauge for electric guitar DADGAD tuning

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning

There's another question on here regarding the string sizes for an acoustic guitar, but no questions regarding an electric guitar. Any ideas? I'd also prefer if people stated the exact size of every string.

Comment: Can't be answered unless we know what gauges you use for standard tuning.

Comment: We can't tell you if you don't tell us. What electric guitar? What strings do you prefer now? What sort of playing will it be used for? Needs work on the question!

Comment: We can’t tell you what’s right for you but you can calculate it. Note your favorite gauges for standard tuning. Then go here and calculate all of your standard tuning tensions: https://stringtensioncalculator.com/ Then change the tuning on the tension calculator and then change the gauges of the strings until all the tensions match. If you edit the question to be “how do I make an open tuning set of strings feel as good as a standard tuning set?” Then I’ll retract my close vote and make this an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different playing styles require different string tensions. Styles that require more bending would be lighter, while rhythm and slide playing would tend heavier. There's a rough center around 10-46 for electric, but *what you prefer will vary.*

I mean, B.B. King played *very* light strings and SRV played *very* heavy strings, both playing electric blues.

There are string calculators that allow you to choose strings with the correct tension for you. D'addario has a PDF, and Stringjoy has a web page where you can order the custom set once you choose it, but your local store likely has singles, so you can choose a custom set for your needs.

Comment: Thank you, someone who understood my question! I'll have a look at that calculator, that is exactly what I need!